# How do I initialize a 2D array using the constructor of another class in Java?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, constructor

I have instantiated a 2D array in the following method:

```
public Seating(int rowNum, int colNum) {
    Guest[][] seatedGuest = new Guest[rowNum][colNum];
```

I would now like to initialize the array using the Guest constructor from the Guest class and I'm not sure how.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, how would you initialize a one-dimensional array?

Comment: You should probably make it a field instead of a local variable.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you wish to initialize all Guests in the array at once? Or just one (and leaving the rest null)?

Comment: Why has T.Land's question been down voted?

Answer (score 0):

This is the reference variable seatedGuest and it is on stack.
You have to assign the object to it which will be on heap.

Here you go :)

```
for(int i=0;i<rowNum;i++){
  for(int j=0;j<colNum;j++){
      seatedGuest[i][j]=new Guest();
  }
}
```

Comment: If you downvote an answer, please comment as to why, particularly for a new user. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Thank you! You and Alexandre have answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

If I interpreted your question correctly, now that you declared the array, you want to initialize every entry with a Guest. How about simply using a for loop and initializing each one normally?

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowNum; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < colNum; j++) {
        seatedGuest[i][j] = new Guest(/* ... */);
    }
}
```

I have to say, though, that this is slightly unusual. It seems strange to declare an array and fill it completely with Guests immediately.

Guessing from the signature of your function, that is a constructor from a class named `Seating`. Apparently your Seating class is holding an array of guests to represent the people seating. This way, as @ElliottFrisch said in a comment, that variable should probably be a field instead of a local variable, because it is information to be kept after the constructor finishes, i.e., after the object is constructed.

Then you could probably define another method, `seatGuest` perhaps, that puts a guest in the array:

```
public void seatGuest(Guest guest, int row, int col) {
    this.seatedGuest[row][col] = guest;
}
```

One last word: your variable should probably be named `seatedGuests` and not `seatedGuest`, right?

Answer (score 0):

The `Guest` constructor is good for instantiating only one instance. The line you proposed,

`Guest[][] seatedGuest = new Guest[rowNum][colNum];`

creates an array of size `rowNum * colNum` with 2D array semantics. However, each individual slots in this array points to a `null` value -- meaning it has not been instantiated. So, assuming you have a `Guest(args)` constructor, iterate through the newly created array to instantiate each value -- for example, using a `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowNum; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < colNum; j++) {
        seatedGuest[i][j] = new Guest( <enter your args> );
    }
}
```

Best of luck on your project and welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Thank you!  That's what I was looking for.  I also appreciate to support on the downvote.